# Mobile app metric: navigation around a specific page

Tags: mobile, metrics, event-tracking

I have an app with multiple different sections on one long page, and I want to generate metrics on how different users navigate up and down the page looking at the different sections (something like a heatmap ideally).

Is this kind of metric commonly measured in mobile apps? Can anyone recommend any metric tracking software that would have this capability?